# Jenkins: How to stop stages from building on SCM push

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a pipeline with multiple stages.
One of them should not be executed when code is pushed from SCM.
It should only execute when we have a Time Trigger or when anyone build the job manually.

This work for Time Trigger but doesn't build my stage if build manually     `when { triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger' }`

This build no matter what. Even on SCM push: `when { not {triggeredBy 'SCMTrigger' }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be used for when the build started by user or time triggered.

```
when {
  anyOf {
      triggeredBy 'TimerTrigger'
      triggeredBy cause: 'UserIdCause'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why when { not {triggeredBy 'SCMTrigger' }} didn't work?